# Issue in Subsetting Lists

Tags: r

I have a list called p1.

```
p1
$ColA
     Var1 Freq
1   asgfg  2.1
2     dds  2.1
3     dfg  4.3
4     dfh  2.1

$ColB
  Var1 Freq
1    A 44.7
2    B 55.3
```

But when I try to use below code for subsetting, I am getting an error. I know we can use p1[["ColB"]]["Var1"]] . But below code is useful in R shiny for filtering. Any idea why below code is not proper?

```
p1[[p1[["ColB"]]["Var1"]]]
```

Sample code in R Flexdashboard

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
    runtime: shiny
    source_code: embed
    theme: cosmo
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(magrittr)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shinythemes)
```

```{r}
 df <- structure(list(ColA = c("gf", "dfg", "er", "gfs", "fdg", "sdf", 
"er", "dgh", "dfg", "sfdg", "jyfj", "asgfg", "jgh", "ghjhg", 
"ghj", "gjgj", "dgrert", "tyew", "ewt", "tyu", "hgj", "hjghj", 
"dsgdg", "yt", "ryuy", "tyutyu", "uiuy", "yoiy", "ret", "e", 
"dsgdfg", "hgdhg", "gfdg", "dghgd", "hdsger", "gdfgd", "gt", 
"fdgd", "sgdf", "gdfsh", "sdfh", "dfh", "dgsh", "fg", "dds", 
"gh", "rth"), ColB = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), ColC = 1:47, ColD = 2:48), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-47L))
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  df <- as.data.frame(unclass(df))
  # percentage of count for categorical univariate ------------------------
  p1 <- list()
  p <- list()
  bs <- names(Filter(is.factor, df))
  for(i in bs)
  {
    p1[[i]] <- as.data.frame(round(prop.table(table(df[,i]))*100,1))
    do.call(rbind,p1) %>% as.data.frame()
  }
  Summary
=================

Inputs {.sidebar} {data-width=140}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
h6(selectInput("Plot1","First Variable",choices = c("",names(df)),width = 200))
    output$filter_2 <- renderUI({
    if (input$Plot1 == "") {
    return()
    } else {
      h6(selectInput("b", label = "Levels", choices = unique(df[,input$Plot1]),multiple = TRUE,width = 200))
    } 
    })
uiOutput("filter_2")
h6(selectInput("Plot2","Second Variable",choices = c("",names(df)),width = 200))
height <- reactive({
    if (input$Plot1 != "") {
        length(unique(df[,input$Plot1]))*60
    } else {"NULL"}
})
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Univariate analysis

```{r}
plotOutput("Plot2")
s_data <- reactive({
   p1[[input$Plot1]][["Var1"]] %in% input$b
  })
Plot2 <- reactive(
      for(i in bs)
      {if (input$Plot1 == i) {
        p[[i]] <- print(ggplot(data=s_data()[[i]],aes_string(x=reorder(s_data()[[i]]["Var1"],+s_data()[[i]]["Freq"]),y=s_data()[[i]]["Freq"],fill=s_data()[[i]]["Freq"]))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ylab("Percentage")+xlab(i)+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1,size = 12))+geom_text(aes_string(label = s_data()[[i]]["Freq"]),size=4,vjust = 1,hjust =1, colour="white")+coord_flip())
      } else if (input$Plot1 == "NULL") {
        ""
      }})
    output$Plot2 <- renderPlot(
      { 
        Plot2()
      }, height  = function() height()
    )
```
````

Hope this gives more sense :) I am trying all possibilities but not getting

Comment: can you show the full code.  Also, use `req(input$Plot1)`  What is `bs` ?

Comment: I would debug this by removing by commenting out the `Plot2' part and get the `s_data`  output as datatable.  Wantted to see if that is the issue.  Also, `== "NULL"` doesn't look right.  Did you meant `is.null(input$Plot1)`

Comment: Yes your right..